# Hide table row with java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide table row using javascript.

This is how I'm doing it now. But I know there is better way to do this.

I have use table for each row and each table has an id.

when select item on drop down according to selection only one row should show on table.

part of my table

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" id="tableOneHDPT1">
          <tr>
            <td width="9%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2" height="30"><strong>Width</strong></td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>Length</strong></td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>Mil.</strong></td>
            <td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>Rolls Per Case</strong></td>
            <td width="9%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>1 Case</strong></td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>2 Case</strong></td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>5 Cases</strong></td>
            <td width="11%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>10 Cases</strong></td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>25 Cases</strong></td>
            <td width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#0471B2"><strong>60 Cases</strong></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="10" align="center"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="PT1Row1">
              <tr>
                <td width="9%" align="center">2''</td>
                <td width="10%" align="center">55 yds.</td>
                <td width="8%" align="center">2</td>
                <td width="15%" align="center">72</td>
                <td width="9%" align="center">N/A</td>
                <td width="10%" align="center">N/A</td>
                <td width="8%" align="center">$4.12</td>
                <td width="11%" align="center">$3.64</td>
                <td width="10%" align="center">$3.04</td>
                <td width="10%" align="center">$2.54</td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
            </tr></table>
```

Drop down

```
<select name="TapeSizeHDPT" id="TapeSizeHDPT">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">&lt;Select&gt;</option>
    <option value="HDPT1">2"x55 yds.</option>
    <option value="HDPT2">3"x55 yds.</option>
    <option value="HDPT3">2"x 110 yds.</option>
    <option value="HDPT4">3"x 110 yds.</option>
    <option value="HDPT5">2"x 1000 yds.</option>
    <option value="HDPT6">3"x 110 yds.</option>
</select>
```

This is my js:

```
$('#TapeSizeHDPT').change(function() {
    if ($('#TapeSizeHDPT option:selected').val() == "HDPT1") {
        $('#PT1Row1').show();
        $('#PT1Row2').hide();
        $('#PT1Row3').hide();
        $('#PT1Row4').hide();
        $('#PT1Row5').hide();
        $('#PT1Row6').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess you mean ROW instead of RAW?

Comment: Can you include the html of the table please?

Comment: Yes sorry for bad English

Comment: I add part of my table. only one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide all the rows in a `<TBODY>`:

```
$('#some_tbody').children().hide();
```

And then show the 1 `<TR>` you want to show:

```
$('#' + this.value).show(); // this.value is from the <select> onchange event
```

For this you'll need a `<TABLE>` with `<THEAD>` and `<TBODY>`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>... THs here ...</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="some_tbody">
    <tr id="HDPT1">...</tr>
    <tr id="HDPT2">...</tr>
    <tr id="HDPT3">...</tr>
    <tr id="HDPT4">...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

instead of all `<TR>`s directly in the `<TABLE>`.

Comment: so my js will be like this $('#TapeSizeHDPT').change(function () {  
  $('#some_tbody').children().hide();
   $('#' + this.value).show();
 
 });

Comment: And you should move the `[id]`s from the `<TABLE>`s to their parent `<TR>`s

Comment: yes your answer is the way i need.but its not working. i just copy your table and test with above script.

Comment: Because a fiddle is worth a thousand LOC: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/TFgwk/ If the `<OPTION>` `[value]`s don't exactly match the `<TR>` `[id]`s, that's no problem. If there's some structure, we can fix that. (Like use only the last character or the number etc.)

Comment: Also, you should use CSS for centering and colors. Don't mess up your HTML with that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize it and write it much shorter as in:

```
$('#TapeSizeHDPT').change(function () {        
   $('#PT1Row'+$(this).val().replace('HDPT')).show().siblings().hide();   
});
```

What we are essentially doing here is getting the number part of the option that was selected and showing the appropriate `tr`, while hiding all its siblings (i.e. all other `tr`s)

Comment: If we're going for optimized lines of code, change the value of the drop down to the ID of the table.

Comment: @awbergs - Yes, keeping the value of the option to the same as the id of the *row* would be most appropriate. Yes.

Comment: Im not sure i understand your answer. sorry about that im just beginner. I don't want to use table for each row (but that is what i have done above. I want to change it.)

Answer (score 0):

Change values of dropdown to numerical 1,2... and then

```
$('#TapeSizeHDPT').change(function () {
    var id = '#PT1Row' + $(this).val();
    $('#table').find(':visible').hide();     
    $(id).show();
})
```

Comment: This #PT1Row is id one of my table. so i have #PT1Row, #PT2Row, #PT3Row etc.... for each row. I dont want to use table for each row. I just want to use <tr> so there will be only one main table and it will have ID.